# Grep and find the Matching FileNames

Tags: shell, unix, grep, sh, ksh

I have a txt file which has list of Prefix Id's , I need to take that and match it against the source directory and get the matching file names and build a list.

Im currently using the below code to achieve this , but im getting only the file for last file name in the list

```
set -A flist $(find $1 -name "*.csv" | grep "`cat ${tempfile}.txt`"
```

There are some 10 matching files but this command returns only the last file , any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the underlying problem? Why do you think you need a list of filenames in an array?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat prefixes.txt
foo_[^/]*$
bar_[^/]*$

$ find
.
./blah
./foo_1.txt
./bar_3.txt
./bar_4.txt
./quux_6.txt
./quux_5.txt
./prefixes.txt
./foo_2.txt

$ foo=( $(find . -name "*.txt*" | grep -f prefixes.txt) )

$ set | grep ^foo=
foo=([0]="./foo_1.txt" [1]="./bar_3.txt" [2]="./bar_4.txt" [3]="./foo_2.txt")
```

Note though that this will break on filenames with whitespace and there is probably a better solution to your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 set -A aRray `find . -name "*" | egrep -f RegExPrefix.txt | sed "s/.*/'&'/"`
```

will depend on your shell. Here is tested with a ksh on AIX (so not a GNU sed and `set -A` create an array)